# WPF: Transfer attached properties from one element to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a WPF behaviour that needs to wrap an existing FrameworkElement in a Grid control.

Take this example:

```
<Grid> <!-- Container Grid -->
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Grid.Row="1"/>

</Grid>
```

This is a simple rectangle in a grid, that contain two rows. Using attached properties, the rectangle is set to appear in Row 1 of the Grid.

If I were to attach my behaviour to the Rectangle, it would wrap the Rectangle in another Grid, and affect the visual tree like this:

```
<Grid> <!-- Container Grid -->
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid> <!-- Wrapper Grid -->
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

My problem is that in this scenario, the Rectangle, now wrapped in a new Grid control, will appear in Row 0, not Row 1 of the Container Grid. The Rectangle's 'Grid.Row' attached property needs reassigning to the Wrapper Grid contol.

**My question is:** Is there any easy way to transfer ALL attached properties (such as Grid.Row, etc) from one FrameworkElement to another? Or can anyone suggest a better approach to solving this problem?

My behaviour NEEDS to ensure the element it is attached to is wrapped (a child of) a panel control (ideally a Grid). The behaviour needs to be flexible, and could be attached to any type of element, in any container, panel, decorator, etc; so could therefore have any number of attached properties that would need honouring.

Just FYI, I'm using the following utility code to perform the wrapping. It's experimental at this stage, and can only handle elements with parents of type Panel (Grid) or Decorator (Border):

```
        public static FrameworkElement WrapFrameworkElementWithGrid(FrameworkElement elementToWrap)
        {
            if (elementToWrap != null)
            {
                var container = new Grid();

                if (elementToWrap.Parent is Panel)
                {
                    // If the element is in a panel (grid, etc) then remove it,
                    // wrap it and replace it in the Children collection.
                    var panel = elementToWrap.Parent as Panel;

                    int childIndex = panel.Children.IndexOf(elementToWrap);

                    panel.Children.Remove(elementToWrap);

                    container.Children.Add(elementToWrap);

                    panel.Children.Insert(childIndex, container);

                    return container;
                }
                else if (elementToWrap.Parent is Decorator)
                {
                    // If the element is in a decorator (border, etc), then remove
                    // it, wrap it and set the Child as the container.
                    var decorator = elementToWrap.Parent as Decorator;

                    decorator.Child = null;

                    container.Children.Add(elementToWrap);

                    decorator.Child = container;

                    return container;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the parent is of an unhandled type, then return the original element unwrapped.
                    return elementToWrap;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When I see code like this, my immediate question is: Why? Why do you need to do this (the wrapping)? What requirement is driving this (i.e. is there not a better way than this)?

Comment: I knew this would be the first comment ;) - It's messy for sure, and I wish there wasn't even a need for it. My behaviour performs transformations (scale/pan/etc) driven by multitouch events (i.e. pinch to zoom). The problem is that that if the same element is both BEING transformed and RECEIVING multiple touch events at the same time, the result is sluggish and jerky. Performing the transformations on a parent container solves this problem. The container solution is already well established ... so I'm left with this wrapping issue.

Comment: To be clear, you want individual scale/transform/etc based on a pinch to zoom style interaction? You don't want to do all items within a particular grid? Because if you do, you should be doing the transformations to the Rectangle's Grid parent then so that the layout is preserved relative to the other child elements...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The behaviour should only affect the element is has been applied to (e.g the Rectangle), and not any other elements that happen to also be in the parent panel. The stock 'TranslateZoomRotateBehavior' already achieves this somehow. I am writing a custom implementation to extend it's functionality.

Comment: There are too many attached properties in WPF that could apply here, so you cannot be as flexible as you want. I think you should just apply those for which you have the need at the moment manually.

Comment: @toadflakz Your first comment is a fair one though. I'm going to revisit the source of the problem, and see if I can solve it in a different way. Regardless of my multitouch/transform specific issues, however, I'd still be interested to know if it's possible to transfer attached properties from one element to another.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear to me. What are you really up to? Do you dynamically build those children in your owner Grid or do you already have a fix xaml design? Is this attached dp issue only about Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties? Can you already design your examle correctly in the first place so you do not need to "wrap" around?

Cound you please tell us more about what you up to?

I know this is more of a comment than an actual answer to your issue but here is how you can find all attached properties:

```
public IList<DependencyProperty> GetAttachedProperties(DependencyObject obj)
{
    List<DependencyProperty> attached = new List<DependencyProperty>();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj,
        new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.All) }))
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd =
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd);

        if (dpd != null && dpd.IsAttached)
        {
            attached.Add(dpd.DependencyProperty);
        }
    }

    return attached;
}
```

So maybe you could load Xaml at runtime and then change things before you decide to display your page.

Take a look at this example:

```
StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader("Page1.xaml");
DependencyObject rootObject = XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as DependencyObject;
ButtoninXAML = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(rootObject, "button1") as Button ; 
ButtoninXAML.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click); 
...
```

Still as much cool this all sounds I would suggest to you to first rethink your app design.

Comment: The solution to this is now academic, as I have found an alternative solution to the problem that created this need. However, I'm still interested in whether this is possible. Let me check out your code, and see if it's a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added: This code is to be part of a WPF behaviour, that would be attached to an element declaratively in XAML. The XAML structure is fixed, not dynamic. The need to wrap at runtime is for convenience to the user ... allowing them to apply the behaviour to ANY element, regardless of what it is contained in. I agree though: If this was a static problem, then manually adding the grid is of course the easier solution.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You could create an attached property that when attached to an object checks if there are other attached properties. By using this.GetValue(dependencyProperty) you will be able to get all their values and then you can do whatever you want...